# Docker containers cannot access internet

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I've tried everything I can think of to get my containers to be able to connect to the internet and it's not the usual DNS issue I see on maybe forums. I'm unable to ping IP addresses for example.

I have tried flushing out all my iptables rules and restarted docker service but to no luck. I've reinstall docker engine and still nothing.

If I use network mode host it works but I don't want to do this, I want to use a bridge network I have created. I've also tried the default bridge network and this does not work either.

I don't understand why but this only suddenly became a problem yesterday, no changes were made, no updates, nothing at all has changed.

I can provide whatever outputs necessary to help!